# Flutter - First tab of the TabBar is not positioned properly

Tags: android, flutter

While working with Tabs in Appbar, we found that after launching the release build of the app, half of the text label of the first tab is outside the screen (only half is visible initially).

**Its happening only in the release build**. In debug mode its showing properly.

Not sure if we are doing something wrong or its a bug actually!

**Screenshot of the release apk after app launch (not rendered properly)**

[image: build apk having issue].

**Screenshot of the debug apk after app launch (rendered properly)**

[image]

This is the code we are using...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: "Text 1",),
                Tab(text: "Text 2",),
                Tab(text: "Text 3",),
                Tab(text: "Text 4",),
                Tab(text: "Text 5",),
                Tab(text: "Text 6",),
                Tab(text: "Text 7",),
                Tab(text: "Text 8",),
                Tab(text: "Text 9",),
                Tab(text: "Text 10",),
              ],
              isScrollable: true,
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.directions_car),
              Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
              Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bug which occur on past versions of Flutter. It was specifically observed on Flutter version 0.10.1-pre.108 as mentioned in the [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23339).

The solution was also provided in the ticket which is to [upgrade to the newer version or the latest version](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23339#issuecomment-474646815).

> upgrade newest flutter sdk ,It is solved

Which was validated by the Flutter team:

> ###### HansMuller commented on Apr 19, 2019
>
> Based on [#23339
> (comment)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23339#issuecomment-474646815)
> I'm going to close this issue. If there's still a problem, please
> reopen it.

As of this writing, the latest Flutter version is 3.10 which was [launch in Google I/O 2023](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/whats-new) last May of this year.